# KOMA-Script: "bad" italic in page header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, italic, scrpage2, slanted

Because of trouble with upright Greek characters, I decided to switch from latin modern to Bitstream Charter (even though I don't really like it). It seems that together with the `mathdesign` package, I'm getting the math features I need.

What I'm observing after switching to Charter is that my page headings, using `scrbook`, will be typeset in a 'bad' italic font instead of the 'nice' italic font that is used in the document body. Please see the following example and have a look at the top of the second page compared to the italic text at the very end of the second page:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Heading}
\lipsum

For comparison:

\textit{1 Heading}

\end{document}
```

In the log, there are no messages about missing fonts.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a "bad" italic font; by default, `scrpage2` typesets the header in a slanted font. Put

```
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\itshape}
```

in the preamble and you're done.

Comment: Oh yes, I think I just didn't have a look at the right documents.

Most probably, this is the intended behavior or `scrpage2`. It does not typeset the page headings italic, but slanted by default, which looks okay with e.g. latin modern, but extremely ugly with Charter (to me at least).

Comment: @Christoph Slanted looks ugly in all serif fonts, to me. :)

Answer (score 11):

Even if you don't use `scrpage2`, the default of the `KOMA-Script` *classes* is to typeset the header in a slanted font. You may change this to italic by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape}
```